# How do i get back my loca data aftern taken updates from server in springsorucetoolsuite?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have saved some code in my local Middle.ui.xml file in SPRING SOURCETOOLSUITE,the same file was also changed by another programmer.Both of us have changed the same file in springsourcetool suite.He had committed that file first,after that i took that file  as "Override and update" ,so i lost my local saved data in my local.How to get back my local data before taken updations?.....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Local data is never permanent.  It gets removed on restarts and many major changes.  If you haven't committed those changes to version control, then you have lost them (unfortunately).